# MongoDB Multiple Connections to Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Why does the MongoDB C# Client 2.0 create a connection to each member of the replica set when Read Preference is Primary (default)?

I have an application with MaxPoolSize set to 100, however it creates 300 connections, one to each node in the replica set. Surely it should just connect to the Primary, once it has identified which node is the Primary from the data received from the seed list?

I have two data nodes and one arbiter. The two data nodes are geographically close to the consuming application, with the arbiter a longer ping time away. Whilst I recognize the need to connect to each on a MongoClient level at least once. **Why is the pool needing to connect to all nodes on each pooled connection?**

I only allow Read Preference of Primary, so it is writing and reading from a single server. The issue is I am getting lots of Connection errors (hence me looking into this and discovering this).

I think the Client should connect to a single server on a pooled connection, either the Primary if writing, a pooled Secondary or Primary when reading depending on Read Preference. It should not connect more than once to the Arbiter.

Am I missing something here? It is causing an issue when I am bursting up my pooled connections and the connections are getting throttled by the Azure load balancer.

My connection string:

mongodb://user:pass@mongo1.domain.com:27000,mongo2.domain.com:27000

Note I do not specify the arbiter, it finds that after querying the replica set, and proceeds to open 100 connections, useless as it has no data.

Comment: Hi James, the driver only uses 1 non-pooled connection for each server. If you hitting your max pool size for each server, then something else is going on. Providing a simple repro would be extremely helpful so we could see some code. (Also, the arbiter should never have more than 1 connection because, as you noted, it has no data).

Comment: Glad to hear this is the way it is supposed to work. I will see if I can create a reproduction of this, I am using 3.0.4 with Wired Tiger (I need the compression).